# Update a list item using Client side object module code and prevent sharepoint list workflow 2013 from been executed

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, client-object-model, console-application

I have a custom list inside our sharepoint online classic team site collection. and i define a workflow 2013 on the custom list. where the workflow will be executed when creating and editing the list items. i also wrote a console application which run on a schedule. where the console application will do some checking and updating the list items using client side object module code.

but inside my client side code, can i  prevent the sharepoint workflow from been executed when i update the item inside my console application code?

Comment: This exact question has been answered here - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222189/stop-workflow-triggering-when-systemupdate-is-called

Comment: @user22079 the sample code provided in this link (which i already read) does not have any comment, or general description of what will the code do exactly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSOM C# code for your reference.

```
Web web = context.Web;
var list=web.Lists.GetByTitle("CustomList");
context.Load(list);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var workflowServicesManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(context, context.Web);
var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();
// get all workflow associations
var workflowAssociations = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(list.Id);
context.Load(workflowAssociations);
context.ExecuteQuery();
var wf = workflowAssociations[0];
List<string> eventTypes = new List<string>() { "WorkflowStart" };
wf.EventTypes = eventTypes;
workflowSubscriptionService.PublishSubscriptionForList(wf, list.Id);                
var listitem = list.GetItemById(1);
listitem["Title"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
listitem.SystemUpdate();
context.ExecuteQuery();
eventTypes = new List<string>() { "WorkflowStart", "ItemUpdated" };//ItemUpdated
wf.EventTypes = eventTypes;
workflowSubscriptionService.PublishSubscriptionForList(wf, list.Id);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. but it does not contain any comment or description, so it will be hard to understand what the code is actually doing.. can u advice more?

Comment: The code mean, set workflow event type to only "WorkflowStart" before update the list item, then reset the event type for the workflow.